# fixing blurrieness with Graphics2D in JAVA

Tags: java, graphics, paint, graphics2d

I was wondering why displaying text in my frame has to be so blury, and i came across this piece of code, which is working by the way

```
public void paint(Graphics graphicsObject){
    if(graphicsObject instanceof Graphics2D){
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) graphicsObject;       
        g2D.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    }
    graphicsObject.drawString("not blurry text display", 200, 200);
}
```

having dificulties trying to understand how this work out.

- how come `g2D.setRenderingHint` is fixing my blurry problem, but i dont use it to paint my string?

Comment: Don't forget to call the `super.paint(graphicsObject)` in your paint method override. Else you are setting yourself up for some serious problems. Also, if this is a Swing GUI, you should not be overriding paint at all but rather the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method override of a JPanel or JComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, what this fixed was not blurring. It was *aliasing*.

Aliasing occurs when drawing functions try to create curvy shapes using a raster image - a matrix of pixels, which are squares. If the lines are not vertical or horizontal, you end up with "stairs" - edges that are jaggy.

Antialiasing is a way to make this effect less visible to the eye, by using additional pixels around the drawn line, which are painted in different tones between the foreground and the background. This cheats our eyes to see the line as "smooth". If you zoom an image drawn with antialiasing, you may notice those pixels around the actual line.

So, actually, antialiasing blurs the line, and this makes it seem smoother to our eyes.

---

As to your actual question - you are using the graphics object to draw the line. You set the hint in the graphics object by accessing the object in its form as a `Graphics2D`. Even though you then go on and use the `graphicsObject` using its regular `Graphics` reference, the method `drawString()` is overridden. This means that it will be activated in the concrete object that implements it, which sees - and uses - the `RenderingHint` hash map where your hint is stored.

Answer (score 1):

> but i dont use it to paint my string?

Why do you think so? Because, you are actually using it.

Nowadays, Graphics is always a Graphics2D object, so your if-statement will be executed.

`g2D` and `graphicsObject` both point to the same object. For the compiler they are two variables of different types, allowing different methods to be called, but at execution time, these two variables actually point to the same object.

So by setting the rendering hint on `g2D`, and this being the same object as `graphicsObject`, drawing the string respects that hint and fixes the blurryness by using anti-aliasing as specified in the hint.